# Pandas, mapping one Dataframe onto another?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem. I have 3 data frames; one is a true/false table [3532x622], the other is a single series of integers[662x1], the other is my main dataframe[3532x8]. The true/false table was create by comparing a series of points to find which ones where inside a polygon, that is why is has the shape it does. I have outlined a diagram below as to what I am trying to accomplish.

```
df_1       df_2                                   df_3    
  0          0      1     2         8     9         0
0 56489    0 True   False False ... False True    0 poly_a
1 45872    1 False  True  False ... True  False   1 poly_b
2 86932    2 False  True  False ... False False   2 poly_c
...        
8 45871
9 89641
```

Convert to:

```
df_2
  0      1      2          8      9
0 56489  np.nan np.nan ... np.nan 89641
1 np.nan 86932  np.nan ... 45871  np.nan
2 np.nan 86932  np.nan ... np.nan np.nan
```

Then map this onto the main dataframe

```
df_3
  0      1 
0 poly_a 56489
1 ploy_a 89641
2 poly_b 86932
3 poly_b 45871
4 poly_c 86932
```

This is what I have started

```
# Creating Example Dataframes
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([56489, 45872, 89657, 56895, 87456])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame([[True, False, False, False, True],
                     [False, True, True, False, False],
                     [False, True, False, True, True]])
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(['poly_a', 'poly_b', 'poly_c'])

# Mapping dataframe 1 onto 2
for i in list(np.where(df_2 == True))[1]:
    df_new = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df_2 == True, df_1.iloc[i], np.nan))
    
df = pd.concat([df_3, df_new], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
import numpy
import pandas

# Creating Example Dataframes
df_1 = pandas.DataFrame([56489, 45872, 89657, 56895, 87456])
df_2 = pandas.DataFrame(
    [
        [True, False, False, False, True],
        [False, True, True, False, False],
        [False, True, False, True, True],
    ]
)
df_3 = pandas.DataFrame(["poly_a", "poly_b", "poly_c"])


def replace_values(row: pandas.Series) -> pandas.Series:

    # Make a copy of df_1 (first row) but flip it to become columns
    c = df_1.T.copy().iloc[0]

    # Use the boolean values from the row as index, replace False with NaN
    c.loc[~row] = numpy.nan
    return c


# Combine 2 and 1
combined = df_2.apply(replace_values, axis=1)

# Add 3
result = pandas.concat([df_3, combined], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```py
print(result)
        0        1        2        3        4        5
0  poly_a  56489.0      NaN      NaN      NaN  87456.0
1  poly_b      NaN  45872.0  89657.0      NaN      NaN
2  poly_c      NaN  45872.0      NaN  56895.0  87456.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it is ugly. I hate all of the df = ... But it works.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([56489, 45872, 89657, 56895, 87456])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame([[True, False, False, False, True],
                     [False, True, True, False, False],
                     [False, True, False, True, True]])
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(['poly_a', 'poly_b', 'poly_c'])

for i in np.array(np.where(df_2 == True)).T:
    df_2.iloc[i[0], i[1]] = df_1.iloc[i[1]][0]
    
df = pd.concat([df_3, df_2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=0)
df = df.drop('variable', axis=1)

df = df.sort_values(0)
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.drop('index', axis=1)

df['value'] = df['value'].astype(str)
df[df.value.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
```